# Problem in Painting with selected Objects 3DS Max 2014

Tags: painting, 3ds-max

Even if I pick objects like two different kind of trees, when I am ready to paint them on the landscape it does not paint them, instead it paints the landscape as long as I press the brush.  I tried picking the objects but still the problem remains.  The final result is painting the landscape with trees.

Comment: There is a proposal (future stackexchange site) dedicated to 3D, called [3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics-modeling-animation?referrer=4bIZIhmQJeWKQcyqcR7pKw2). Have a look at it